# Iterating through ArrayList <Object<String>>

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, loops

I'm having some trouble iterating through `ArrayList`. I have a class named `Row` which extends `ArrayList<String>`. I have another class named `Table` which extends `ArrayList<Row>`.

I am trying to iterate through the Table class to convert the `ArrayList` of Rows to a two-dimensional array of Strings.

Here is my code for the `Table` class:

```
public class Table extends ArrayList<Row>
{
public Row[] appArray; //Array of single applicant details
public String tableArray[][]; //Array of every applicant
private ArrayList<Row> ar;
private Row r;

public Table()
{
}

public void addApplicant(Row app)
{
    add(app);
    displayable();
}

public void convertToArray()
{
    int x = size();
    appArray=toArray(new Row[x]);
}

public void displayable()
{
int i,j;
for (Row r: ar)
   i=0;
    for(String s: r){
        j=0;
        tableArray[i][j]=s;
        j++;
    }

}}
```

and here is the `Row` class:

```
public class Row extends ArrayList<String>
{
public Row(String appNumber, String name, String date, String fileLoc, String country, Table table)
{
    addDetails(appNumber,name,date,fileLoc,country);
    table.addApplicant(this);
}

public void addDetails(String appNumber, String name, String date, String fileLoc, String country)
{
    add(appNumber);
    add(name);
    add(date);
    add(fileLoc);
    add(country);
}}
```

The method i am having trouble with is `displayable()` in the `Table` class. It tells me `i may not have been initialized` However if I initialize it in the second for each loop it will only iterate through the first element in my `Table ArrayList`?

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Setting `i` and `j` to `0` *inside* their respective `for` loops seems like a possible logic error to me.

Comment: There's no such thing as an `ArrayList<Object<String>>`, because class `Object` does not have type parameters (`Object<String>` is invalid).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The displayable method has two errors:

- the first for-loop does not have {}
- i is not incremented (i++; missing)

code:

```
public void displayable()
{
  int i,j;
  for (Row r: ar){
    i=0;
    for(String s: r){
        j=0;
        tableArray[i][j]=s;
        j++;
    }
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think what such increment isn't something desired, as each of counters becomes zero again on next iteration.

So there is also need to move `i=0` and `j=0` one level up

Comment: It works! Thanks for all the help guys. Silly mistakes can be such a hassle. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

You just missed block in `for (Row r: ar)` loop.

Also, as [Fortega](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109880/fortega) noted, you never increment `i` in your code, and I suppose that you zero your counters in wrong place.

So, instead of:

```
for (Row r: ar)
   i=0;
   for(String s: r){
     j=0;
     tableArray[i][j]=s;
     j++;
   }
```

You should write something like:

```
i=0;
for (Row r: ar) {
  j=0;
  for(String s: r){
    tableArray[i][j]=s;
    j++;
  }
  i++;
}
```

Or better to narrow down visibility area of counters and join declarations with initializations:

```
// Remove previous declarations

int i=0;
for (Row r: ar) {
  int j=0;
  for(String s: r){
    tableArray[i][j]=s;
    j++;
  }
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
for (Row r : ar)
            i = 0;
        for (String s : r) {
            j = 0;
            tableArray[i][j] = s;
            j++;
        }
```

to:

```
for (Row r : ar) {
            i = 0;
            for (String s : r) {
                j = 0;
                tableArray[i][j] = s;
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
```